# SQL recursive CTE with two tables

Tags: sql, sqlite, recursion, common-table-expression

Trying to wrap my head around recursive CTEs but having some trouble. I've got two tables, one for employees and one for departments. I'm trying to write a recursive CTE that starts with an anchor department and goes through all sub-departments, returning a set of employees that have foreign keys to the anchor department or any sub-departments.

Here is a simplified version of the employee table

```
employeeID     name               departmentID
1              Brad Fisher        1
2              Alex McCabe        2
3              Amy Calvin         2
4              Daniel Struthers   4
```

And the department table. The parentID simply referring to other departments in the same table.

```
departmentID    name                      parentID
1               Company Operations        0
2               Guest Services            1
3               Staff Services            1
4               IT Support                3
```

Below is the CTE I have put together. As long as there is at least one employee in each level of the department hierarchy, it will return a full list of all employees starting at the top. But the issue is that if there is a department in the hierarchy with no employees, it breaks the recursion there.

```
WITH EmployeeDepartmentHierarchy(employeeID, name, departmentID)
AS (
   SELECT e.employeeID,
          e.name,
          e.departmentID
   FROM Departments AS d
   INNER JOIN Employees AS e ON d.departmentID = e.departmentID
   WHERE d.name = "Company Operations"
   UNION ALL
   SELECT e.employeeID,
          e.name,
          d.deparmentID
   FROM Departments AS d
   INNER JOIN EmployeeDepartmentHierarchy AS edh ON edh.departmentID = d.parentID
   LEFT JOIN Employees AS e ON d.departmentID = e.departmentID
   )
   SELECT * FROM EmployeeDepartmentHierarchy
```

I'm trying to fix it so that it will go down the entire hierarchy of departments and only terminate if there are no sub-departments found, rather than terminating when it reaches a department with no employees.

Comment: You can (LEFT) JOIN the employees table later,in the outer query.

Comment: Messing around with the code, it seems that replacing the INNER JOIN with a LEFT JOIN in the anchor section fixed my problem... Though I'm not sure why entirely.

How would you go about your solution exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/905902/wildplasser) already commented, get the departments without employees in a CTE and then left join them in the outer query.

```
WITH dh
     (departmentid)
AS
(
SELECT d.departmentid
       FROM departments d
       WHERE d.name = 'Company Operations'
UNION ALL
SELECT d.departmentid
       FROM departments d
            INNER JOIN dh
                       ON dh.departmentid = d.parentid
)
SELECT e.employeeid,
       e.name,
       dh.departmentid
       FROM dh
            LEFT JOIN employees e
                      ON e.departmentid = dh.departmentid;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.16&fiddle=30220a9a3963d2fc8b22502de01dc8f4)